# Cannot allocate memory error from spark-submit to AWS EMR give

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am posting ten spark-submit requests consecutively through Apache Livy to my EMR cluster running YARN but spark gives following error on 7th submit and all submits afterwards:

> "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   \"/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit\": error=12, Cannot allocate memory"

Is there any way so that spark-submit goes in a queue and would only get executed once getting resources and my job won't fail.

Comment: enable ganglia on EMR and observe the free memory in master node (where livy is running); Does this happen when the node memory crosses 90%? --then this is livy issue --in which case try to space the livy submits so that u dont submit more than 1 or 2 in 5 sec; see if this helps

Answer (score 3):

‘There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue’. This warning indicates a shortage of memory available on the master node to run the Java Environment. This behavior is common if the master node is under a heavy memory load, which can starve the other processes that utilizes memory.

In order to remediate this issue, it is recommended to launch an EMR cluster with a higher instance type to leverage more memory as per cluster's requirement.